# looking for an efficient way to iterate

Tags: python-3.x, performance, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

may i ask for suggestion to iterate more efficiently (and faster)?
here is the issue, I am looking for a way to propagate zeros down in a pandas DataFrame within a determined window size:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

A = np.matrix([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
           [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])

df = pd.DataFrame(A)
```

now we want to fill by increment of windows of 3 lines each
the values from the top. 
each window of 3 lines starts on window_start, defined as:

```
window_size = 3
window_start = [i for i in range(0, df.shape[0]) 
                if i % window_size == 0]
print(df)
gf = df.copy()
print('\n')
```

now making the DataFrame where the zeros propagate from the 
preceding lines above inside that window:

```
for i in window_start:
for j in range(1, window_size):
    try: gf.iloc[i + j] = gf.iloc[i + j - 1] * gf.iloc[i + j]
    except: pass

print(gf)
```

This last bit is pretty inefficient and time consuming for very large datasets, is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this task with a cumulative product within a `groupby`.

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).cumprod()

      0    1    2    3    4
0   0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1   0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
3   1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
4   1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
5   1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
6   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
7   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
8   1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
9   1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
10  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
11  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
12  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
13  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
14  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
15  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
16  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
17  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
18  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
19  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

We can take a better look, by using `concat` to see if it's doing what we want.

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:6, :2], d1.iloc[:6, :2]], axis=1, keys=['Before', 'After'])

  Before      After     
       0    1     0    1
0    0.0  1.0   0.0  1.0
1    1.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
2    1.0  1.0   0.0  0.0
3    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
4    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
5    1.0  1.0   1.0  1.0
```

***My Take on a `numpy` approach***
*See @Divakar's solution as I borrowed some elements of his function*

```
def prop_zero(df, window_size=3):
    a = df.values
    W = window_size
    m, n = a.shape

    pad = np.zeros((W - m % W, n))
    b = np.vstack([a, pad])

    return pd.DataFrame(
        b.reshape(-1, W, n).cumprod(1).reshape(-1, n)[:m],
        df.index, df.columns
    )

prop_zero(df)
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if the values overflow, e.g. `[1e200, 1e200, 0]`, because cumprod will generate `[1e200, inf, nan]`. ;-) #unlikelyfailuremodeoftheday

Comment: Nice hashtag :-)

Answer (score 5):

You could do a `groupby` with `cummin`:

```
In [46]: out = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).cummin()

In [47]: df.head(6)
Out[47]: 
     0    1    2    3    4
0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
5  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

In [48]: out.head(6)
Out[48]: 
     0    1    2    3    4
0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
5  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

This assumes that all values are 0 and 1.  If you have non-1 values but you still want the zero-after-zero behaviour, you could do something like

```
df.where(~(df == 0).groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).cummax(), 0)
```

which isn't as pretty, but doesn't get confused by values like 0.5 (as applying `cummin` directly to the values does) or by potential overflow (as applying `cumprod` directly to the values does).

Comment: This works so long as values are 1's and 0's.  Great answer!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a NumPy approach splitting the first axis giving us a `3D` array, then using `cumprod` along first axis and then reshaping back to `2D`. For the cases where where the number of rows are not divisible by the `window_size`, we would have leftover elements that won't be part of the reshaping and those would be processed seprately.

Thus, the implementation would be -

```
def numpy_cumprod(df, window_size=3):
    a = df.values
    W = window_size
    m,n = a.shape
    N = m//W
    M = N*W

    out0 = a[:M].reshape(-1,W,n).cumprod(1).reshape(-1,n)
    out = np.vstack(( out0, a[M:].cumprod(0)))
    return pd.DataFrame(out)
```

Sample run -

```
In [279]: df
Out[279]: 
    0  1  2  3  4
0   2  2  2  0  1
1   1  2  0  2  2
2   1  1  0  0  1
3   2  0  2  0  1
4   0  0  0  1  0
5   0  0  1  2  1
6   1  1  0  0  1
7   0  0  1  2  1
8   2  2  2  1  1
9   2  1  2  1  0
10  1  1  1  1  2
11  0  2  2  1  2

In [280]: numpy_cumprod(df, window_size=3)
Out[280]: 
    0  1  2  3  4
0   2  2  2  0  1
1   2  4  0  0  2
2   2  4  0  0  2
3   2  0  2  0  1
4   0  0  0  0  0
5   0  0  0  0  0
6   1  1  0  0  1
7   0  0  0  0  1
8   0  0  0  0  1
9   2  1  2  1  0
10  2  1  2  1  0
11  0  2  4  1  0
```

Runtime test on bigger dataset -

```
In [275]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,3,(10000,5)))

# @piRSquared's soln-1 using pandas groupby
In [276]: %timeit df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).cumprod()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.49 ms per loop

# @piRSquared's soln-2 using NumPy
In [261]: %timeit prop_zero(df, window_size=3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 285 µs per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [262]: %timeit numpy_cumprod(df, window_size=3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 262 µs per loop
```

Comment: This is what I was going to add :-)  I was going to append a padded set of zeros at the end then remove them again.

Comment: @piRSquared Lovely addition there, added that into the timings as well. Pretty fast now.